# transfer $database->loadObjectList() ; to another array error

Tags: php, joomla

```
$propertyList[]=  ($database->loadObjectList() );
```

AS database var is ,, `$database =& JFactory::getDBO();`

The Result ->

```
Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
             [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 1
                    [text] => Apartment
                )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 2
                [text] => Duplex
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 3
                [text] => Villa
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 4
                [text] => Paint house
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 5
                [text] => Chalet
            )
}}
```

How could i transfer all the data without `( [0] => Array )` in the other array as i wanna read the components into drop down list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you loading it into $propertyList[]? Using the "[]" will add it onto the array. If you would remove those 2 brackets, you shouldn't get an array with an array.

```
$propertyList = $database->loadObjectList();
```